# Writing a Function at specific memory location of Flash

Tags: flash

I want a function to go at specific memory location of Flash and I am not able to figure it out.

Do I need to do modification in Linker File?

Also, I have idea that in GCC, I would use #pragma directives by which I can put my code in specific section but don't know how to assign that section to specific address.

I am using Keil and programming LPC2138.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put a function in a section with GCC, use a function attribute

```
extern void foobar (void) __attribute__ ((section ("bar")));
```

Then, declare a section called `bar` in your linker script. Eg.

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx): ORIGIN=0xDEADBEEF, LENGTH=0x80000000
}

SECTIONS
{
  .bar:
  {
    KEEP(*(.bar))
  } > FLASH
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joby. But has anyone tried this with Keil??

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_bcfjbabb.htm http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_BABDGIFE.htm